# Magento static CMS block in XML layout with two or more storeviews

Tags: layout, magento, content-management-system, block, cache-control

I have two static CMS Blocks called "promo_en" and "promo_de" - translated for the two existing storeviews "en" and "de".

I'd like to add them to the sidebar of some modules using the layout.xml files of the modules.

The problem is that if I add them both using the following syntax - they both show disregarding the storeview I'm currently in (I would expect some automatic filtering):

```
<block type="cms/block" name="Promo_de">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_de</block_id></action>
</block> 
<block type="cms/block" name="Promo_en">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_en</block_id></action>
</block>
```

If I rename them both to "promo" and use the following syntax - it works fine until I activate Magento's cache - then the output of the CMS block freezes on whatever storeview is cached first:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="Promo">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo</block_id></action>
</block>
```

And ideas or workarounds on the matter are highly appreciated.

Comment: Or is there at least some way of disabling cache for this block using the XML syntax? The Magento documentation on that topic is nearly non-existent in my opinion...

Comment: Can you do this with theme over-ride file? As per the French, German and English theme views of the demo store?

Comment: Matthew's suggested solution is semantically more correct.

Comment: I think the theme override is worth a deeper look for a more permanent solution but I couldn't find a quick tutorial and the customer wants it finished...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing my own Mini-Module to quickfix the problem, switching the translations in code based on the current store code:

```
if( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'de' ) 
{
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('promo_de')->toHtml();
} 
else if( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'en' ) 
{
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('promo_en')->toHtml();
}
```

I know it's ugly but time really was an issue here and I'll have to clean this up in the future...

Comment: The clean way seems to be the theme override Matthew suggested - you should have a look at it before using this solution which is nothing more than a quickfix...

Answer (score 27):

As a rough workaround you can use [layout handles](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) specific to each store. For example;

```
<STORE_de>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="Promo_de">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_de</block_id></action>
        </block> 
    </reference>
</STORE_de>
<STORE_en>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="Promo_en">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_en</block_id></action>
        </block> 
    </reference>
</STORE_en>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'd have loved to use this way because it would be just a quickfix for a promotion box the customer wants on certain modules - but unfortunately magento just ignores the layout handles... no idea why...

Answer (score 14):

Why not create the static blocks with same identifier, and then only enable them in corresponding store view?

```
<block type="cms/block" name="Promo">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Then create 2 static blocks with identifier promo and only enable them in storeview where they belong?